# Display out of stock products of specific category in list and search result page

Tags: magento2, category, catalogsearch, out-of-stock

I have enabled Show out of stock products in the admin Inventory section.

I have to show all in stock and out of stock products of one category(**id=10 and its subcategory**) in list and search result page. by hiding all out of stock products in remaining categories(But should show all in-stock products).

So when we are in category page(**id is 10**) need to show all in_stock and out of stock,

category page(**id is not 10**), Need to show only in_stock products.

If in the search result page, have to show both in_stock and out_of_stock(only from category id 10).

I used the below plugin.

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder">
  <plugin name="Custom_Layernavigation::CustomLayernavigation"
  type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder" />
</type>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Search\RequestInterface;

class IndexBuilder {    
protected $_request;
protected $_categoryHelper;
 protected $_logger;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory   = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function aroundBuild($subject, callable $proceed, RequestInterface $request) {
    $select = $proceed($request);

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');     
    $collection->joinField(
        'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
    );
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['gt'=>0])->load();
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(array('cat_index'=> 'catalog_category_product_index_store1'), "cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id")
        ->where('cat_index.category_id <> 10');

    return $select;
  }
}
```

Can someone update me on how to implement this functionality? I am unable to write a join query to match the above requirement. Please check and update me about this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using magento 2.4 then you have to create a plugin for

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer

We have to set the Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options->Display Out of Stock Products. This is necessary because Magento doesn't load the is_in_stock filters when we set this option to 'NO'. So we can't put our custom work/conditions when it sets to NO I've debugged it completely and well , So first we have to set it to YES , then I've created a plugin for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer`and I've handled in such a way that it is now working properly. 1- The Out Of Stock and In Stock products will be shown for specified category 2- Other all the categories of the store will only show InStock products according to our requirement.

The code is below:

```
 public function aroundPrepareProductCollection(CatalogLayer $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    // Getting current category Id
    $categoryId = $subject->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    // Getting specified category whom we wann show OOS products
    $showAllCategoryId = $this->displayBoth->getShowAllCategoryId();

    if($categoryId == $showAllCategoryId) {
        //Get Out Of Stock Products and also In Stock Products of the specified category
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=0 || is_in_stock=1');
        // Apply to the collection
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $categoryId]); // Current category filter, it's not require, because PrepareProductCollection() automatically apply filter for current category.
    }else{
        //Get only In Stock products to the all the categories instead of above specified one
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1');
        //Apply to the collection
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $categoryId]);
    }
    return $proceed($collection);
}
```

This has been tested well and working fine for Magento 2.4 EE and CE

Comment: I have a problem with count and pagination using this method. So for example I have 13 SKUs with 12 per page. On page 1 I see SKUs 1 to 11. On page 2 I see 1 SKU. So the OOS SKU has been removed from the listing but not considered in count or pagination. Did you have a similar issue?

Comment: I am facing same issue(the one you mentioned in your comment), did you find any solutions for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do using **afterPlugin** method by this below way :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search;

class IndexBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function afterBuild($subject, $result)
    {
        if(your_category_id){
            $connection = $result->getConnection();
            $result->joinLeft(
                ['stock_status_filter' => $connection->getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status')],
                'search_index.entity_id = stock_status_filter.product_id'
                . $connection->quoteInto(
                    ' AND stock_status_filter.website_id IN (?, 0)',
                    $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId()
                ),
                []
            );
            return $result;
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure display out of stock products configuration enabled.

Hope, Maybe it's helpful for you.

Comment: hi @Rohan, Thanks for the answer, but the above code may work only for category page, I can use registry and get the current category and use it, but in search result page this will fail, this will not come inside if condition

Comment: Okay. wait please.

Comment: Did you created any plugin for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer ?

Comment: No i have not created any plugin for that? But i am using Bss layered navigation extension, they have re-written it

Comment: Also I checked ur code now only for categories, problem is out of stock products showing for all other categories also
we have to show only in_stock for other categories except one category(there both in_stock and out_of_stock) should show